# Visual C++ 2008 bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The very simple code (under MS Visual C++ 2008 Express):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int a=1; 2*a<=7; a++)
        cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Debug** mode gives me **correct** result:

```
1
2
3
```

But **Release** mode gives me **wrong** result:

```
1
2
```

Well, I understand possible answers "use 2*a<8"; "why not a<=3", "a<4".

I don't want to change the code, 'cause it is correct code (working well in Debug mode, all variables are initialized well, etc).

- Have you the same bug with Visual C++ 2008 Express?
- Is this bug present in younger versions (2010, 2012)?
- How to avoid this bug?
- Is there SP for fixing it?
- Maybe to change some compile options (not default options)?

---

**Update:**

when I write

```
cout << a+1 << endl;
```

or

```
cout << 2*a << endl;
```

it works/compiles correct (**3** rows of output).

---

**Note:**
I tried on different computers with VC++ 2008 Express. The same behavior.

Comment: Redirect the output to a file and make sure it's in fact incorrect rather than some display/buffering issue in whatever you're looking at the output with.

Comment: Or step through with the debugger and see that the code actually *is* executing.

Comment: Is that the exact code you're running? If so, how are you viewing the output before the console closes? Did you just set a breakpoint at the end and hope the last output is executed before that?

Comment: @Mat, Under debuger I see "mov esi, 1" and then comparing esi with 2. I think it is not output problem.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: under "cmd.exe", for example.

Comment: If VS wasn't able to handle a simple for loop, you couldn't compile anything with it. Are you 100% certain your binary matches your source (i.e. did you do a clean build)?

Comment: This behavior does not appear in my VC 2013. Both in debug and release mode.

Comment: @Xiangyan Sun: Thank you for the info: one of the ways to fix it (upgrade).

Comment: @Mat This is not a **simple** loop, do you ever need to write such kind of code? There were multiple for-loop related optimization bugs present until the release of VC 2012. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/08/10/10338661.aspx (search "loop")

Comment: @Mat, build by default: without any additional changes/options: and in **Release mode** it generates me (asm): MOV ESI, 1; ...; INC ESI; CMP ESI, **2**; JLE ___;

Comment: @Oleg567 What about using `printf` or other kinds of operations? I have found some possibly related VC bugs. I wonder maybe VC inlined some code from `cout` and something triggered a bug. Or could please paste the full assembly output?

Comment: @Xiangyan Sun: just now tried to modify into      printf: without success. It is interesting, that     printf("%d\n",a);  working wrong, but    printf("%d\n",a+1); working correct.

Comment: Does repro with `cout::flush()` before `return`? Sry, but I don't have an old VS laying by to test.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu, stream works correct: cycle generating working wrong: **2 loops only**.

Comment: If you don't want to change the code (it's your code, you have the right not to change it) maybe you'll have to change your compiler. According to others' comments, an upgrade should be enough.

Comment: Works correctly in 2012 and 2013 w/optimizations. I say bug, not that MS is going to be in any hurry to fix it.

Comment: @Xiangyan Sun: Thank you for the link of bugs. I found here other weird bug for very simple loop: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729818.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can repro that on VS2008 SP1.  It is a code optimizer bug, as usual.  You'd have to look at the disassembly to see the cause.  It fumbles at `2*a <= 7` when it factors out the multiplication, it generates code for `a <= 2`.  That's wrong of course, should have been `a <= 3` or `a < 4`.  Looks like it doesn't handle the <= operator correctly for divisions.  Kinda tricky, it has to know the difference between odd and even numbers :)

The bug disappears when you don't force it to figure out how <= behaves with division, using `2*a < 8` works fine.

This bug has been fixed a while ago, I don't know exactly when since the bug reports for these old versions have been deleted from the public site.  Best way to deal with optimizer bugs is to give them a chance to fix them, keeping your compiler updated is pretty important.  You've got 3 newer versions of the Express edition to choose from, that's two dog lives in compiler development.  Three with C++11 around :)